# XMLHttpRequest() SetInterval

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, setinterval

My setInterval is firing, but it seems the `XMLHttpRequest();` is not going through?

I get the first `console.log()`, but not the second.

Any insight into this would be highly appreciated.

Code below:

```
var countdown = 1000;
var region = "the_Pacific";
var jsonrequestInterval = function () {
    console.log("The clock was updated");
    var jsonrequestIntervaled = new XMLHttpRequest();
    jsonrequestIntervaled.open("GET", 'myURL' + region, true);
    jsonrequestIntervaled.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (jsonrequestIntervaled.readyState == 4) {
            console.log("The request was made");
            if (clock.getTime() >= jsonrequestIntervaled.responseText.match(/-?[1-9]\d+/g)) {
                clock.setTime(jsonrequestIntervaled.responseText.match(/-?[1-9]\d+/g));
            }
            if (time > 300) {
                countdown = 10000;
            } else if (time < 60) {
                countdown = 1000;
            } else if (time < 300) {
                countdown = 5000;
            }
        }
    };
};
//problem not updating!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
setInterval(jsonrequestInterval, countdown);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do `jsonrequestIntervaled.send();`to make the call

Comment: It's always the simplest things that escape me. :P

Thank you so much!